# Method swizzling for "alloc"?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I try to use method swizzling for catching "**alloc**" for **NSObject** generic.

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
UIView *view  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
[...]
```

This is the implementation (category .m), that *works on all others methods*, **except alloc on NSObjet**.

What could be the cause?

```
#import "NSObject+Custom.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (Custom)

+ (void)load
{
  Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(alloc));
  Method swizzle  = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(allocCustom));
  method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzle);
}

- (id)allocCustom
{
  NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); // no way
  return [self allocCustom];
}

@end
```

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`+alloc` is a class method, not an instance method:

- Use `class_getClassMethod` instead of `class_getInstanceMethod`
- `+allocCustom` instead of `-allocCustom`

Comment: correct. Obviously that is a class method!.. inadvertence, thanks!